# mysql++ examples not compiling mysql.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c++, mysql, compilation, compiler-errors, mysql++

Whenever I attempt to compile some examples from the **mysql++** library, I got the following error:

```
In file included from /home/testbed/Tools/mysql++-3.1.0/lib/cmdline.h:32:0,
from multiquery.cpp:32:
/home/testbed/Tools/mysql++-3.1.0/lib/common.h:189:20: fatal error: mysql.h:
No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I have all the MySQL libraries installed and when I search for the mysql.h file, it is displayed!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need the mysql *development* libraries (packages)

Comment: Right, I attempted to compile it in codeblocks instead of the terminal by pointing to the location of the header file, now I am getting /home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|33|fatal error: printdata.h: No such file or directory|

What do?

Comment: are you using `./configure` and `make` ?

Comment: Apparently I have installed these, Mr Horvath- maybe I there is some confusion on my behalf. 

What packages should I have installed?

Comment: I am simply attempting to compile a .cpp file into an executable
Running Linux Mint 14 64-bit, by the way

Comment: I have found some sort of related problems here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/5259/

It seems that I am missing some packages and in my hubris I was adamant that I wasn't. 

Which packages do I need to install? Sorry, I am a newbie

Comment: I've fixed the "file not found" errors, the libraries seemed to be installed though they were not being pointed to.

Comment: I am getting the following errors now:

obj/Debug/main.o||In function `print_row':|
/home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|64|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::operator<<(std::ostream&, mysqlpp::String const&)'|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `print_multiple_results':|

Comment: /home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|123|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Query::store()'|
/home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|126|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Query::store_next()'|
/home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|125|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Query::more_results()'|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `main':|
/home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|136|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::examples::CommandLine::CommandLine(int, char* const*, char const*, char const*, char const*)'|
/home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|148|undefined reference to

Comment: `mysqlpp::Connection::Connection(bool)'|
/home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|149|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Connection::set_option(mysqlpp::Option*)'|
/home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|153|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::examples::db_name'|

Comment: /home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|153|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Connection::connect(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'|
/home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|158|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Connection::query(char const*)'|
/home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|191|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Connection::~Connection()'|

Comment: /home/testbed/multiquery1/main.cpp|191|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Connection::~Connection()'|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `mysqlpp::examples::CommandLine::print_usage() const':|
/home/testbed/Tools/mysql++-3.1.0/lib/cmdline.h|139|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::examples::CommandLine::print_usage(char const*) const'|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function

Comment: `mysqlpp::MultiStatementsOption::MultiStatementsOption(bool)':|
/usr/local/include/mysql++/options.h|234|undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlpp::MultiStatementsOption'|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `mysqlpp::Row::operator[](int) const':|
/usr/local/include/mysql++/row.h|328|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Row::at(unsigned long) const'|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult::operator=(mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult const&)':|
/usr/local/include/mysql++/result.h|252|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult::copy(mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult const&)'|

Comment: obj/Debug/main.o||In function `mysqlpp::Query::str()':|
/usr/local/include/mysql++/query.h|278|undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Query::str(mysqlpp::SQLQueryParms&)'|
||=== Build finished: 17 errors, 0 warnings ===|

All of these are in the query.h header file